# Integrating Moodle and ASP.NET Identity 2.1

Tags: single-sign-on, asp.net-identity, moodle

**TL;DR**: I'd like to make a Moodle installation and an ASP.NET Identity-based site share authentication. If they have a single login page, so much the better, but logging in to one should automatically log into the other; logout should also be shared.

---

I have a Moodle installation (**M**) at *www.example.com/moodle*, and another website (**O**) at *www.example.com*.

- **O** is written using .NET 4.5.2 and has areas that require authentication to access, managed using ASP.NET Identity 2.1 with a custom user model. This model is not particularly sophisticated. It is essentially the out-of-the-box model, but with integer IDs rather than GUIDs.
- **M** is version 2.6, with intentions to upgrade to the latest version (currently 3.1) in the near future.
- Both are accessible via the public Internet; there is no requirement to be on a private network to access them.
- I know of no plans to move either **M** or **O** onto a different domain. However, if one or both was to move, I imagine they would move to a subdomain of *example.com*.

I would like to create a single-sign-on system, allowing a login for **M** to also log the user into **O**. As it stands, I am using the external database authentication plugin for Moodle, with **M** referring to the database for **O**. While this works, it does require the user to log in twice. I would like to set it up so that logging in to either **M** *or* **O** will also log the user in to the other site.

- I am able to create matching hashes from PHP and .NET code. Unless it is particularly relevant to the solution, please consider the creation of hashes out of scope.
- Some users of **M** are using Moodle's built-in authentication. However, unless it is particularly relevant to the solution, please consider the migration of users out of scope.
- I'd prefer **O** to manage users, if possible. **M**, by nature of being Moodle, will have to have its own records for the users, but I'd like it if they were similar to the records used by the external DB plugin: just saying that the user exists and can be found elsewhere.

**Things I have tried, investigated, or considered:**

- Moodle's external database plugin. This is how it works at the moment. It sort of works, but requires multiple logins.
- Automating the multiple logins. I've experimented with taking the posted credentials, making a HTTP request from the server to the sites' respective login forms when logging in, lifting the cookie out of the response, then sending that cookie back to the client. This also works, but it's clunky at best, and is reliant on the cookies not getting out of sync.
- Using PHP's DOTNET library and doing...something. All of the documentation that I can find says that DOTNET does not work with anything other than .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5. I'm using 4.5.2, so this seems like a no-go. I don't know what I'd do even if I could get it to work with more recent versions of .NET.
- Somehow getting Moodle to accept the ASP.NET Identity cookie in place of its own. This seems like the most fruitful course, given that it is a single cookie to manage.

**To wrap up:** I'd like to make **M** and **O** share authentication. If they have a single login page, so much the better, but logging in to one should automatically log into the other; logout should also be shared. Is this possible, and does anyone know how I should go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at SAML.

I believe that .NET 4.5 supports SAML?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

On the server, install simplesamlphp.

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp

It can be used both as a service provider and as an identity provider.

Then install this SAML plugin in Moodle :

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml